# GoF Design patterns Bridge/Adapter/Decorator

Tags: design-patterns, adapter, decorator, bridge

I am reading up on design patterns, and there is a question I don't feel I can answer myself. Are Adapter, Bridge and Decorator structurally different, or are they coded the same but just applied with different semantics?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Structurally, the patterns are very similar.  A lot of the difference is in the **intent** of the pattern and not the way they are built.

The **adapter** pattern is used to adapt a class with one interface to that of another interface.  Typically, the class you are adapting is legacy code or in a library that you can't access (or at least can't change).  One key difference with the adapter is that the interface that you are adapting and what you are providing back are **different**.

The **bridge** pattern is very similar to adapter, in that it can bridge a class with one interface to that of another interface.  However, the key difference is **intent**.  With the bridge pattern, the class was explicitly designed to work this way.  The developer will still have access to the class that is being delegated to, but the developer intentionally chose to design it this way.

The **decorator** pattern will return the same interface of the class that is being decorated.  It is used to **extend the behavior** of an existing class, not to change its interface.

Comment: Actually, about the decorator pattern, it's important to emphasize that in fact you're extending the behavior of an existing **object**, not the class. Other objects from that class will remain unmodified.